# Bootstrap padding issue on mobile view gallery

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm having an issue with a gallery in Bootstrap. It works and looks fine in desktop view, but when I resize to mobile view, there is no padding between the images on the same row.

When on mobile, the images from a given row are stacked on top of each other. There's no vertical separation between them, but there is vertical separation between the 4-image groups that would make up a row on larger screens. I suspect it's related to my CSS, though the line below ought to fix it.

```
#rowpadding{
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Here's the [template of the gallery](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/4-col-portfolio/). And here's [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/billgoldbergmania/zj2qwtmk/9/), which shows the phenomenon I describe.

Comment: Please include some code in your question, not just a link (which is not even clickable).

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this css and your problem will solve.

```
.container .row {
margin-bottom:0px!important;
```

}

```
.portfolio-item {
margin-bottom: 25px;
```

}

Remember one thing don't use same id's in a page. Remove this id 'rowpadding'

Comment: @kaper Man Thanks !!